# Select the cases by comparing the second elements of the list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a list:

`l={{1,4},{2,4},{3,5},{4,6},{5,3},{6,2}}`

How can I select the elements of the list in the second element is decreasing and first element of the list increasing? That is, I want `{{1,4},{2,4},{5,3},{6,2}`?

I know there is a simple function in Mathematica to do this. But I cannot find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[LongestOrderedSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestOrderedSequence.html)

If your input list is already sorted by the first column:

```
LongestOrderedSequence[l, #[[2]] >= #2[[2]] &]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}

In general, for arbitrary list of pairs not necessarily sorted by the first column:

```
LongestOrderedSequence[l, And[#[[1]] <= #2[[1]], #[[2]] >= #2[[2]]] &]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}

Answer (score 3):

Version 10.1 doesn't have `LongestOrderedSequence`.  For the sorted case I might therefore use:

```
Reap[ Fold[If[#2[[2]] > #, #, Sow[#2][[2]]] &, ∞, l] ][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}
> ```

Compiled function for better performance:

```
 Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{list = Internal`Bag[Rest[{0}], 2]},
     Fold[If[#2[[2]] > #, #, Internal`StuffBag[list, #2, 2]; #2[[2]]] &, a[[1, 2]], a];
     Internal`BagPart[list, All] ~Partition~ 2
   ]
 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope nobody minds me practicing. The idea is to take differences between sequential elements and apply an `If` step according to the sign.

Here is an ugly and dirty way to do it with `Table`. I need `Prepend` because g does not work for the first element in l, which is always in the result. I then delete redundant cases (zeros).

```
l = {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}
g[t_] := l[[t - 1]] - l[[t]]

DeleteCases[
Prepend[Table[
If[g[t][[1]] >= 0; g[t][[2]] <= 0, l[[t]], 0], {t, 2, Length[l]}], 
l[[1]]], 0]
```

Same thing using a Do loop (avoids redundant cases) and repartitioning l by applying a function that gives the differences. They are then fed in the loop.

```
l = {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}
res := {}
h[x_, y_] := {x - y}
elem = Flatten /@ Partition[l, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, h]
```

> {{-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 3}, {-1, 1}}

```
res = Append[res, l[[1]]]; Do[
If[elem[[i, 1]] >= 0; elem[[i, 2]] <= 0, 
res = Append[res, l[[i + 1]]],], {i, 1, Length[l] - 1}]
```

Annoyingly I cannot make Do work from i=2 instead of 1, which would simplify even further.

In both cases the output is

> {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

If ordered by first column:

```
list = {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}};

DeleteDuplicates[list, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]
```

{{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
l = {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}};

SequenceReplace[l, {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} ->  
  If[a > c || b < d, Nothing, Sequence @@ {{a, b}, {c, d}}]]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {5, 3}, {6, 2}}